Autofill Service via Flutter on Password-Manager App
I am currently working on the Flutter App which acts similarly to a Password Manager and consists of basic features such as saving passwords and using them in another app, For ex: let's say I saved my account detail for google in my app including (Mail and Password) then I go to google app and try to login but at that time my app will suggest me my saved username and password so I can just autofill my way out of this easily!
How to do this in Flutter for android App
Im trying to fetch those saved password from flutter app and suggests me on other app credentials
